# Webdriver verify order of floats descending - Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to verify that the floats ("data" attribute) I find are in descending order. Here is what I have so far:

```
list = self.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_Selector, "locator")
for i in list:
    data = i.get_attribute("data")
```

Should I even be doing this in a for loop? I'm pretty new to Webdriver and coding in general.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the variable name `list` as it's a Python keyword.

If `data` is indeed an attribute of `i` you can simply do:

```
for i in my_list:
    data = i.data
```

Or more usefully, do something like:

```
data = []
for i in my_list:
    data.append(i.data)
```

Or even shorter:

```
data = [i.data for i in my_list]
```

You can then check for descending order by comparing `data` to the sorted version of itself:

```
print 'data is in descending order:', data == sorted(data, reverse = True)
```